# Trouble loading data from arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In swift I have the array as follows:

```
var storedLevels = [
    1:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],

    2:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

I need to be able to load the array `storedLevels[1]` to a variable,
then loop through the values in the variable.

At this time I have everything working, however I have to explicitly set the 1 as X in `storedValues[X]` then loop through that code.

This is the function i'm using:

```
func loadLevel(level: Float) {
        var x: Int = 0
        var y: Int = 0

        let blocks = storedLevels[1]

        for var i: CGFloat = 0; i <= (gBlockCountY); i += 1 {
            y = Int(i)
            for var i: CGFloat = 0; i <= (gBlockCountX-1); i += 1 {
                x = Int(i)

                var blockCountToTimes: CGFloat = CGFloat(y)-1
                if blockCountToTimes < 0 {
                    blockCountToTimes = 0
                }
                let blockNumber = (gBlockCountX * blockCountToTimes) + CGFloat(x)

                if let block = blocks?[Int(blockNumber)] {
                    addBlockToGrid(CGFloat(block), x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y))
                } else {
                    addBlockToGrid(1, x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I make `let blocks = storedLevels[1]` use the value passed to the function (`level: Float`) to replace the 1?

Comment: your array looks more like dictionary

Comment: @Lamar Any idea of how to make it work?

Comment: first off, the compiler IS type casting this as a dictionary, I just verified this by using your own code. I also verified that is will type cast an array as an array by my removing the "1:" and setting the value to just the "1s", so this is something you should look at first, then see if you have an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`storedLevels` is a dictionary of type `(Int, [Int])`, not an array. I don't know why you need to have the key (and hence makes it a Dictionary). This will also do just fine:

```
var storedLevels = [ [0, 0, 0, ...], [1, 1, 1, ...] ]
let blocks = storedLevels[Int(level) - 1]
```

Now back to your dictionary: your key is of type `Int` but `level` is a `Float`. Can there be level 1.5? If you want to go with the dictionary paradigm, cast `level` to an `Int`:

```
let blocks = storedLevels[Int(level)]
```

Comment: I figured it out, but this is exactly what I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, I'm storing stuff inside an NSMutableArray of arrays, this works, no hardcoding, and you don't have to change your code:

```
var storedLevels = [
    1:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],

    2:[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

var sf = NSMutableArray(capacity: storedLevels.count)
var countert = 0
for s in storedLevels.values.array {
    sf[countert] = s
    countert++
}
println(sf)
```

This will give you an Array of the Arrays you want. to get the array you want out of this Array of Arrays, then you just extract them one by one from the Array holding all arrays.

for example, if I write

```
println(sf[0])
```

I get this:

> (
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       0,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1,
>       1 )

and to top it off, here's your function:

```
func loadLevel(level: Float) {
    var sf = NSMutableArray(capacity: storedLevels.count)
    var countert = 0
    for s in storedLevels.values.array {
        sf[countert] = s
        countert++
    }
    println(sf[(Int(level)-1)])
}
```

call this method using this:

```
loadLevel(1.0) or self.loadLevel(1.0)
```

and it works